# A manga about a man in a slice-of-life isekai manga about eating otherworld foods

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's a black and white manga, with not many chapters, maybe 50-ish at max, where a black-haired dude (main character) and his maid (female MC) go around eating foods like dragon steak to a magic water apple. She likes him, and the MC's goal is to basically eat every rare otherworld food he can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [*Gourmet in a Different World*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/111721/Gensou_Gourmet) (AKA *Gensou Gourmet*).

The main character travels the world with his maid eating exotic foods. The first chapter is about him having dragon steak and the 11th is about him eating water fruits.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thank you ‍♂️!

Comment: @ViceTurtle - [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)